# Name of movie about little girl that moved to forest camp run by Nazis, with her mother

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Movie title may have Pandora in it. Movie opens with 1940's open car carrying little girl & her mother to a big house in the woods. A small flying creature accompanies the car. The girl finds a way to enter other worlds with exotic people & situations; e.g. a giant that has to put its eyeballs in the palms of its hands in order to see. At the end the the girl is to be executed but ends up in a magical kingdom, real or imagined.

Comment: Pan's Labyrinth.

Answer (score 7):

### [*Pan's Labyrinth*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0457430/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)<sup>1</sup>

The plot focuses on Ofelia, a little girl who moves with her mother to a military camp located in some Spanish woods. As hinted, the soldiers are [Francoist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Franco) soldiers, not Nazis, although [you could be forgiven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francoist_Spain) for getting them mixed up.

Ofelia encounters some faerie-like creatures who lead her to a faun, who informs her that she's the reincarnation of the underworld princess Moanna; in order to reclaim her heritage, she has to complete three trials. One of those trials is to steal from the "Pale Man", a terrifying creature whose eyeballs are in his hands:

[image]

The film constantly plays with the ambiguity around Ofelia's fantastical adventures; most of the human characters insist that she's making up excuses for what they see as disobedient behaviour, but she insists that they're real (and some things happen that are hard to explain otherwise).

At the end of the film, Ofelia is killed by her stepfather, who is also the leader of the camp, but the final scene suggests that Moanna successfully returned to the underworld.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically the film is titled *el laberinto del fauno*; but in the English-speaking world it's generally known by the translation

Comment: You ninja you. I need to write my own. ;)